# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC application in a shared hosting without losing the beautiful uri?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I am trying to upload an ASP.NET MVC application in a shared server running on IIS 6 and Windows 2003. I don't have access to IIS. I've changed the `global.asax.cs` file as follows:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = "" }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

It is working fine, but it doesn't drop the `.aspx` at the end of the controller. Is there a way to remove the `.aspx` extension in the URL?

Comment: do you know what version of IIS you are running on? If you are on 7 make sure you are running in integrated pipeline mode

Comment: With Gearhost, I just asked them to change that setting and they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you're URI's should work off the bat providing you are on IIS7.

If you are on IIS6 however you will need to jump through some hoops to get extensionless URI's.

This guide may help - [haacked.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

As far as I can tell though you'll need access to handler mappings in IIS6, which you probably won't have on your shared host.

Comment: the haacked tutorial was very useful.thanks. but i have no IIS access..:( no use in being happy if the application works perfectly well in the development machine alone, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's because your host has not set IIS to send all requests through ASP.NET. The only thing you can do is to ask your host to change this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Change the host. Seriously. Shared hosting STILL using IIS 6 - that is brutal. Hosts should have switched over quite some time ago.

Comment: said very easily...:) i am stuck with a client who has already bought the space and the provider is least responsive...:(