# Unable to upload asp.net mvc3 website on windows hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I purchased a windows hosting and a domain now when i build my code and upload it to server and try to access that then following list appears

[image]

and i cannot view the website . What could be the problem . Please guide me and thanks

Comment: Contact the hosting provider. They deal with questions like this all the time and should be able to give you the right answer.

Comment: possible duplicates: [Is there a way that I can run a ASP.NET MVC Project on godaddy.com shared web hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266205) [How to deploy ASP.NET MVC application in a shared hosting without losing the beautiful uri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446907), [How to deployed Mvc Application on shared-hosting Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735185)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy ASP.NET MVC application in a shared hosting without losing the beautiful uri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446907/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-application-in-a-shared-hosting-without-losing-the-bea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the file name to the URL in your browser's address line. If that works, then the server is not recognizing that as the default file name. You can set up the server to do that.

Default.aspx is normally the default file name for asp.net. If you don't have a file named that, you can either rename one or append the file name to the URL.

Comment: xpda, I don't understand how Default.aspx has anything to do with MVC

Answer (score 1):

Setup your project to send out MVC specific DLL's (do not come with .NET framework)

- Rightclick your mvc web project
- Click on Add Deployable dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS and Disable Directory Browsing